# Unable to call object properties from functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, object

I am new to JavaScript and wanted to create a simple game of pong for practice.
I can easily draw the gaming area on the canvas but now there is some problem when I try to draw the bat.

I created a playerBat object with some properties.

```
var playerBat = {
    batWidth:20, 
    batHeight:100, 
    x:10, 
    y:(height/2)-(batHeight/2), 
    spdY:10
};
```

Then in the function "drawPlayerBat" I simply drew a rectangle with these properties as parameters.

```
function drawPlayerBat() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(playerBat.x, playerBat.y, playerBat.x+playerBat.batWidth, playerBat.y+playerBat.batHeight);
};
```

But its not working ! The console says "Unable to get property 'x' of undefined or null reference". Have I made any mistake in syntax or doing this is just not possible ?

Here is the entire code... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqgVog?editors=1010

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: The console also says `Uncaught ReferenceError: batHeight is not defined`. That causes the code to terminate, so `playerBat` is never defined.

Comment: @SandeepNayak how moving playerBat above setInterval will help?

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answers, please mark them, so this question won't show up as unresolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Easy fix:**

There is really no reason to call

```
y:(height/2)-(batHeight/2),
```

since you are defining batHeight two lines above it. It won't behave dynamically - once you set it it won't change when `batHeight` changes, it will stay the same.

Knowing `batHeight` value you can simply say that

```
y:(height/2)-(50),
```

**What answer you probably want:**

If the question is about self-referencing in JavaScript, then the answer would be to set the values inside of a function inside of the object and initialize it after declaring it. For example:

```
var playerBat = {
    batWidth: 20, 
    batHeight: 100, 
    x: 10, 
    spdY:10,
    init: function(){
        this.y = (height/2)-(this.batHeight/2);
        return this;
    }
}.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove batHeight. Do it like below.

```
 var playerBat = {
        batWidth:20, 
        batHeight:100, 
        x:10, 
        y:(height/2)-(100/2), 
        spdY:10
    };
```

Comment: That worked for me. Thank you !